# Spark History Server (SHS)FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm using the latest Spark 3.3.0 but still got the exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /LOG_DIR/application_1657344020931_1400038_1.inprogress`

which contradicts https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/29350 , how could it be?

In LOG_DIR there are 70k eventlogs.
One SHS is running on nodeA with Spark2.4.5.

In order to resolve the exception,I run a new SHS one node B  with Spark 3.3.0 ,but still got  the exception.

The basic problem is that some finished spark applications randomly cannot be seen from the SHS.I think the `FileNotFoundException` is the main cause and the PR is aimed to resolve it.

Comment: What execution engine are you using? YARN or standalone or local?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer I am using YARN mode with YARN 3.2

Comment: So, 1} you can't run two versions of Spark for the same application. 2) Are you sure all nodes in the cluster have the same hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, and core-site.xml?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer Thank You for the reply. I found the cause and answered it below. By the way, I disabled the cleaner in my new SHS, and new  SHS and the old SHS can share the same event logs

Answer (score 1):

I re-checked the whole `FsHistoryProvider.checkForLogs(...)` and found that I misunderstood the PR.

**My question:** SHS always shows less (COMPLETED) apps than the number of event logs(exculde `inprogress`) in my LOG_DIR

This situation will always happens because when SHS found an untracked log eg. `aaa._inprogress`, at the moment `checkForLogs` is writing the `aaa._inprogress` to LevelDB, Spark renames it to `aaa`, thus `FileNotFoundException` happens and the loop is aborted.

So the rest of the logs which may be 10% of all apps in the loop are missed. That's why my SHS less so many than the LOG_DIR.

THE PR above skip such problematic `aaa` event logs in this loop, but next time, since `aaa` is not in LevelDB, it will be tracked.
SHS still show less than the num of eventlogs, but just 40~70 apps  in my cluster and these apps will show soon